# Can a smart contract with multiple addresses send those funds elsewhere in a single txn?

Tags: addresses, smart-contract

I'm looking to create a smart contract to receive both ETH and USDC. The smart contract needs to be able to provide a unique address to each customer so that I can tell who has paid and who hasn't without collecting the address they are sending from. I'm fairly sure that part is possible, but if anyone has any guidance please let me know.

Ideally, however, I'd need to be able to send the assets each unique address receives. If for example customer A has paid into address 1 and customer B has paid into address 2, and they have each paid 10 ETH, can I send 15 ETH in one transaction using those funds? Similarly, if address 2 has 100 USDC instead, can I send that USDC if there is no ETH in address 2?

Comment: yeah, you can accumulate any (amount of) token(s) or plain ETH  on the contract for a few days, then send all these funds in a single transaction (provided that the tx doesn't overflow the gas limit of the entire block) to any other address. A contract in Ethereum is very powerful thing and can do lots of stuff nowadays

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about the part "... without collecting the address they are sending from" every tx has msg.sender which is the sending address. One example should make things clearer. Also the term "smart contract with multiple addresses" is also not clear, do you mean your contract controls multiple external addresses?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.